# What is TargetDeviceFamily MinVersion/MaxVersionTested for Windows 11?

Tags: uwp, windows-11, appxmanifest

If I have Windows 10 running build 19045.3324 then I know the format for the app manifest TargetDeviceFamily MinVersion/MaxVersionTested is `10.0.19045.3324`.

But if I have Windows 11 running build 22621.2506, is it `10.0.22621.2506` or `11.0.22621.2506`?

And can you link to the documentation for this as I've not been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick search and determined that it is the former.

https://www.lifewire.com/windows-version-numbers-2625171
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11_version_history